# Масштабирование (zoom) окна без изменения размера окна в PotPlayer

Tags: масштабирование, пк, плеер

Подскажите, есть ли возможность сделать масштабирование видео в плеере PotPlayer на ПК. Например как в плеере Samsung на телефоне, или как это делает экранная лупа на ПК.
Заранее спасибо!

Пример нужного функционала на гифке[image: масштабирование окна на телефоне в плеере Samsung]